# Application of Gronwall's lemma (square function)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

I wanna use Gronwall's lemma to this inequality:
$$\frac{d}{dt}f(t)^2\leq A(t) f(t)$$
I thaught of using $ab \leq a^2+b^2$
then we'll have:
$$\frac{d}{dt}f(t)^2\leq A(t)^2+ f(t)^2$$
But how can I use the Gronwall's lemma in this case

Comment: Well $\frac{d}{dt} (f^2) = 2f \frac{df}{dt} $ so the inequality reduces to $2df/dt \le A$ (as long as $f$ doesn't hit 0, anyway)

Comment: but what we can't do the simplification that you made

Comment: What are the (possible) properties of $f$ that would make the chain rule and factorization non-applicable?

Comment: @AnasBOUALII Sorry, can you clarify: is that "but what--we can't do the simplification that you made!?" or "but what [if] we can't do the simplification that you made?"